# codeigniter Mysql join Query result

Tags: mysql, codeigniter, join

I have three tables.
users,
products (user_id is foreign key),
reviews_ratings (user_id & product_id are foreign keys)

mysql query is

```
$pid = some id;
$this->db->select('*');
$this->db->from('reviews_ratings');
$this->db->join('users', 'users.id = reviews_ratings.user_id');
$this->db->join('products', 'products.id = reviews_ratings.product_id ');
$this->db->where('reviews_ratings.id >', $pid);
$this->db->order_by('reviews_ratings.id', 'DESC');
$this->db->limit(1);
```

In result,

```
Array ( [0] => stdClass Object ( [id] => 14 [title] => blaaa [review] => blaaaa [rate] => 4 soooo on))
```

`[id]=>14` is not the id of review_ratings table. 14 is the product_id. everything is good except this `[id]` value. i want review_ratings id value in `[id]`.
please help me to correct it.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use group by...

```
$pid = some id;
$this->db->select('*');
$this->db->from('reviews_ratings');
$this->db->join('users', 'users.id = reviews_ratings.user_id');
$this->db->join('products', 'products.id = reviews_ratings.product_id ');
$this->db->where('reviews_ratings.id >', $pid);
$this->db->order_by('reviews_ratings.id', 'DESC');
$this->db->group_by('reviews_ratings.id');
$this->db->limit(1);
```

Comment: it returns id=14 because you are checking `products.id = reviews_ratings.product_id `or show me the tables update your question

Comment: problem solved now. thanks for your time and comment @gopalbhuva

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved by adding this line

```
$this->db->select('products.*,users.*,reviews_ratings.*');
```

instead of this

```
  $this->db->select('*');
```